# How to get parameters from view to controller in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, parameters

here is my view

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlists">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is my state templating

```
  .state('app.single', {
    url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

and here is my controller

```
.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

});
```

how to get the parameters from the view in the controller?

Comment: Please check answer and more for ionic use https://github.com/learning-ionic

Answer (score 2):

Use the following :

```
 .controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

    //In playlistId your input param 
      var playlistId = $stateParams.playlistId;

    //more...
 });
```

Hope this will help you !!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access the variable from

> stateParams

```
 .controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.id= $stateParams.playlistId;  
}
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Any state URL parameters are available by name in `$stateParams`, eg

```
$stateParams.playlistId
```

Also, you should be using `ui-sref` instead of `href` in your HTML links

```
ui-sref="app.single({playlistId: playlist.id})"
```